# How to define different Spring MVC request handlers for requsest with and without request parameters?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

Has Spring MVC any way to define different handlers for request without request parameters and request with request parameters?

There is a simple controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/strategies")
public class StrategyController {
    ...

    @GetMapping
    public List<Strategy> getAll() {
        return service.getBeans().stream()
            .map(mapper::toDto)
            .collect(toList());
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<Strategy> search(StrategyFilter filter) {
        return service.search(new StrategySearchSpecification(
                filter.getCode(),
                filter.getName(),
                filter.getType()
            )).stream()
            .map(mapper::toDto)
            .collect(toList());
    }
}
```

I want `getAll()` method to handle requests without request parameters:
`/strategies`

And I want `search(StrategyFilter filter)` method to handle requests with request parameters:
`/strategies?name=SomeName&type=SomeType`

It seems that it's not possible to distinguish such cases through `params` attribute of `@GetMapping` since any property of `StrategyFilter` can be omitted.

In this configuration I get an obvious error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. 
Cannot map 'strategyController' method 
public List<Strategy> StrategyController.getAll() to {[/strategies],methods=[GET]}: 

There is already 'strategyController' bean method public List<Strategy> StrategyController.search(StrategyFilter) mapped.
```

**Ofcourse it's possible to write something like this:**

```java
@GetMapping
public List<Strategy> get(StrategyFilter filter) {
    return noFilterProvided(filter) ? getAll() : search(filter);
}
```

But It would be necessary to change 'noFilterProvided(StrategyFilter filter)' every time when number of attributes of filter changes.

Comment: Add the "noFilterProvided" method as a helper to the parameter POJO, e.g. add an `isEmpty()` *(or `isUnfiltered()` or whatever name you prefer)* method to `StrategyFilter`, which returns true if all fields are null, then do the `return filter.isEmpty() ? getAll() : search(filter)` logic. --- I mean, really, what is the difference between `getAll()` and `seach(null, null, null)`, other than a potential performance improvement in underlying service / DAO?

Comment: Yes, there is no difference but I wanted to write less logic code and wondered can spring mvc do such job for me. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring framework uses a point based matching. It selects the highest match from the available ones. The more criterion passing ones get the higher points. if you define requested query parameters in one matching it will accepted when the params exists. Other cases the the other one.

To define requested parameters pass them as direct attributes, not as a StrategyFilter attribute. The initialization of instances like this success in the case of missing parameters as well (those attrs won't be initialized, they stay in their default state : ""/0/false). So ambiguous matching error occures.

Finally : use direct attributes instead of StrategyFilter.

Other problem with your design is the direct StrategySearchSpecification instantiation. It is not unit testable in this way. Define it as a Spring Component.

```
@Component
@Getter // Lombok annotation to generate getter methods
@Setter // Lombok annotation to generate setter methods
public class StrategySearchSpecification
{
  private CODE_TYPE code;
  private String name;
  private TYPE_TYPE type;
}
```

And inject it as a parameter (right implementation/mock) and use the setter methods of it.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/strategies")
public class StrategyController {
    ...

    @GetMapping
    public List<Strategy> getAll() {
        return service.getBeans().stream()
            .map(mapper::toDto)
            .collect(toList());
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<Strategy> search(@RequestParam CODE_TYPE code, @RequestParam String name, @RequestParam TYPE_TYPE type, StrategySearchSpecification specification ) {
        specification.setCode( code );
        specification.setName( name );
        specification.setType( type );
        return service.search( specification
            )).stream()
            .map(mapper::toDto)
            .collect(toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: While I don't like to instantiante mutable and much more inconsistent empty objects, solution with multiple @RequestParam seems fine, thanks alot!

There is no problems to unit test controller since there is no need to mock Specification 'cause it's pretty simple. it has nothing static inside and there is just single rewritable implementation 'cause no need to have multiple dao implementations at one time in project.

When it became much complex it's possible to inject Factory instead of Specification to achieve immutability and polymorphism when it would be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If `StrategyFilter` has the attributes `name` and `type`, this should work:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/strategies")
public class StrategyController {
    ...

    @GetMapping
    public List<Strategy> getAll() {
        return service.getBeans().stream()
            .map(mapper::toDto)
            .collect(toList());
    }

    @GetMapping("{name}/{type}")
    public List<Strategy> search(StrategyFilter filter) {
        return service.search(new StrategySearchSpecification(
                filter.getCode(),
                filter.getName(),
                filter.getType()
            )).stream()
            .map(mapper::toDto)
            .collect(toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution looks brittle for me as far as I should come and fix mapping every time StrategyFilter has changed. But I didn't knew about existance of such solution, thanks!

Comment: I didn't notice that `{name}/{type}` is not params property value. So since it's path parameters, it seems that such solution is not suitable when no `name` attribute must be provedied.